# AttributeError: 'H2OFrame' object has no attribute 'to_html'

Tags: python, h2o, dataspell

I just installed the most recent version of h2o for Python.

And it generates the following error:

```
import h2o
h2o.init()
h2o_df = h2o.H2OFrame(some_df)
```

the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\JetBrains\DataSpell 2022.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_console_utils.py", line 417, in execTableCommand
    success, res = exec_table_command(command, command_type,
  File "C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\JetBrains\DataSpell 2022.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_tables.py", line 43, in exec_table_command
    res += repr(tmp_var.head().to_html(notebook=True,
AttributeError: 'H2OFrame' object has no attribute 'to_html'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\JetBrains\DataSpell 2022.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_console_utils.py", line 417, in execTableCommand
    success, res = exec_table_command(command, command_type,
  File "C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\JetBrains\DataSpell 2022.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_tables.py", line 43, in exec_table_command
    res += repr(tmp_var.head().to_html(notebook=True,
AttributeError: 'H2OFrame' object has no attribute 'to_html'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\JetBrains\DataSpell 2022.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_console_utils.py", line 417, in execTableCommand
    success, res = exec_table_command(command, command_type,
  File "C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\JetBrains\DataSpell 2022.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_tables.py", line 43, in exec_table_command
    res += repr(tmp_var.head().to_html(notebook=True,
AttributeError: 'H2OFrame' object has no attribute 'to_html'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\JetBrains\DataSpell 2022.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_console_utils.py", line 417, in execTableCommand
    success, res = exec_table_command(command, command_type,
  File "C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\JetBrains\DataSpell 2022.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_tables.py", line 43, in exec_table_command
    res += repr(tmp_var.head().to_html(notebook=True,
AttributeError: 'H2OFrame' object has no attribute 'to_html'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\JetBrains\DataSpell 2022.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_console_utils.py", line 417, in execTableCommand
    success, res = exec_table_command(command, command_type,
  File "C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\JetBrains\DataSpell 2022.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_tables.py", line 43, in exec_table_command
    res += repr(tmp_var.head().to_html(notebook=True,
AttributeError: 'H2OFrame' object has no attribute 'to_html'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\JetBrains\DataSpell 2022.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_console_utils.py", line 417, in execTableCommand
    success, res = exec_table_command(command, command_type,
  File "C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\JetBrains\DataSpell 2022.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_tables.py", line 43, in exec_table_command
    res += repr(tmp_var.head().to_html(notebook=True,
AttributeError: 'H2OFrame' object has no attribute 'to_html'
```

It also dumps all previous calls and output of h2o. What is wrong here?

**UPDATE**

I guess I have to add that I am running it in DataSpell. Everything seems to be fine in Jupyter notebook.